# Error en setInterval de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Tengo un problema, he realizado una función que ejecuta un `setInterval`.

La primera vez que se llamó a la función funciona correctamente (cada segundo) pero cuando la llamo variadas veces, el tiempo se descontrola como si estuviera ejecutando los `setInterval` de las llamadas anteriores.

¿Cómo se puede resetear el tiempo para que funcione siempre a un segundo?

```
function ejecutar_timer(){
  var valor = 0;
  clearInterval(timerId);
  timerId =  setInterval(function(){
    valor = valor + 1;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La idea es que uses `setInterval` y guardes su ID para que luego puedas detenerlo cuando quieras usando `clearInterval`. Puedes lograr esto con una variable global.

Te dejo un ejemplo usando dos botones:

```js
var timerId = false;

function ejecutarTimer(){
    var valor = 0;
    // Para evitar que se ejecute nuevamente si ya está corriendo
    if (!timerId) {
        timerId = setInterval(function(){
            valor = valor + 1;
            document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML = valor;
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function detenerTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="ejecutarTimer()">Iniciar</button>
<button onclick="detenerTimer()">Detener</button>
Contador: <span id="contador">0</span>
```

Observa, que estoy validando que no se esté ejecutando previamente el timer antes de crear uno nuevo:

```
if (!timerId) {
    // ...
}
```

Y que el timer lo estoy reiniciando a `false` cada vez que se ejecuta la función `detenerTimer`

Answer (score 1):

SetInterval ejecuta la función CADA x milisegundos, solo se deberia ejecutar una vez, para que se ejecute una única vez o para usarlo recursivamente es setTimeout.
Luego, piensa que la variable valor está dentro la función ejecutar_timer, no se puede acceder desde fuera.