# Error en setInterval JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php

tengo esta funcion:

```
function socket(sucursal = null,n=null) {
  var scan_new_pedidos = setInterval(function () {
    $.post("api.php",{request:"npedidos",id_sucursal:sucursal},'',"HTML").done(function(npr){if(parseInt(n) < parseInt(npr)){f5();}});
  }, 30000);
}
```

y la llamo asi

```
socket(1,<?php echo $pedidos_count;?>);
```

donde $pedidos_count es la suma de todos los pedidos actuales que tengo (ejemplo: 5)

> mi api.php me devuelve la suma de todos los pedidos.

Esto lo hago para cada 30 segundos consultar cuantos pedidos tengo y si la respuesta es mayor que los pedidos actuales la web se recarga para mostrar todos los pedidos.

el problema esta en que al ejecutarse el script va bien pero luego de 3 o 4 consultas se vuelve loco y comiensa a enviar consultas en un tiempo aleatorio.
Nota: no uso otro codigo javascript que me pueda estar generando esto ya que yo pobre aislando solo esta funcion e igual siempre se aloca el setinterval.

La pregunta es: estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: No lo tengo nada claro, la verdad, ¿pero has probado limpiando el interval con `clearInterval(scan_new_pedidos);` antes de asignar `scan_new_pedidos`? (antes, fuera de la función, pon un `var scan_new_pedidos;` para que no te dé error).  Es que segun me parece se estan solapando varios setInterval a la vez porque cada vez que se actualiza el dato debes estar relanzando esa funcion de nuevo, supongo.

Comment: @masterguru respecto a : "No lo tengo nada claro, la verdad" intente explicarme pero no se como mas ponerlo amigo, bueno aver el setInterval al detectar que la respuesta es mayor al numero que tengo "n" se actualiza la web con un location.reload() quiere decir que se refresca todo el html, js, y css asi que no necesito un clearinterval

Comment: tengo este mismo problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6740/error-en-setinterval-de-javascript?rq=1 solo que de el es una solucion diferente

Comment: no, no, perdona, el "no lo tengo nada claro" no tiene que ver contigo ni el contenido de tu pregunta, el cual se entiende bien... soy yo que no estoy nada seguro de la solucion que te estaba dando, por eso lo decia, perdona la confusion